# Pass request to different class based on routing logic

Tags: python

This is very similar to [Pass request to different class based on condition Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60991654/pass-request-to-different-class-based-on-condition-python) but I decided to create another question as the answer in that question was correct but not applicable to my use case. My question was poorly worded and changed.

I am designing an API which deals with different type of vehicles for example cars, buses and vans. There is an endpoint `POST /vehicle` which will take a defined body.

```
{
'registration': 'str',
'date_of_purchase': 'datetime str',
'vehicle_type': 'car'
...
}
```

The API entry point goes to vehicles.py which does some logic.

The first thing that we do is load an object based on the vehicle_type.

```
if body[vehicle_type] == 'car':
   passed_in_vehicle = Car(body)
elif body['vehicle_type'] == 'bus':
   passed_in_vehicle = Bus(body)
...
```

After this, we call a method called get_manufacturer() which will call a third party service with the registration number and get the name of the manufacturer of the vehicle. We then want to route it to the correct manufacturer class.

Within the python program there are multiple classes including:

- ford_service.py
- jaguar_service.py
- bmw_service.py

Each class has the same set of base methods.

- update_vehicle_specs
- register_vehicle

At the moment in the bottom of vehicles.py I have

```
if manufacturer = 'BMW':
   bmw_service = BMWService()
   bmw_service.register_vehicle(passed_in_vehicle)
elif manufacturer == 'FORD':
   fordService = FordService()
   fordService.register_vehicle(passed_in_vehicle)
...
```

However, this cannot be scalable. What is the correct solution to route to specific classes based on a condition?

Comment: Why can't you call `get_manufacturer` in `__init__` of the vehicle type (e.g. `Car`)?

Comment: Because of the pattern we are using. The model should only be a model and no have any logic. It shouldn't be making third party API calls when initilising.

Comment: Can you call it before? That would be a pattern that makes sense to me - a vehicle should know its registration from the get go.

Comment: A vehicle knows it's registration but does not know the manufacturer (as well as far more details) until we call the third party API. We cannot call it until the point we are at unfortunately.

Comment: I think this is a design question. In order for readers (and me) to better understand, I think you should point the entire chain of relevant code - initializing vehicles, getting manufacturers, and finding the correct service. For instance, what do you pass get_manufacturer? Why is it only available after initializing the vehicle object? These seem pertinent to the question.

Comment: I have had to try simplify the code as there are 2,000 lines of logic between when the Car object is initilised and the API call is made to get the manufacture details. The key is we cannot have the manufacture before this point. It is just not possible.

Comment: ... and you guys are completely against a `.register` method? Thing is, the logic for registering has to be somewhere. If you don't put it in the individual classes, then your solution (or variants, `locals()`, dictionary, etc...) is the only way. It seems odd though you initialize a service (which presumably services all cars of said manufacturers) for each new car. Perhaps you need a dictionary of Services with the keys being manufacturers initialized at the beginning?